# Android "Сворачивать" уведомление по умолчанию

Tags: android, kotlin, уведомления

Создаю `Notification` следующим образом

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val ch = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(ch)
}
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Hello")
        .setContentText("Hello!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build()
```

После чего показываю его.

Сейчас уведомление как гром среди ясного неба всплывает на экране, как можно сделать так, чтобы оно сразу отправлялось в Status bar(Ну или как оно там правильно называется) к остальным уведомлениям?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH

Вы сами указали ему быть громом среди ясного неба.

---

- `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`  По умолчанию значение уведомления: показывает
  везде, шумит, но визуально не вмешиваться. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` ‎Большее значение уведомления: показывает везде, делает шум и заглядывает.
- `IMPORTANCE_LOW` ‎Низкая важность уведомления: показывает везде, но не навязчивым. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_MAX` Неиспользуемые. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_MIN` Значение min уведомления: показывает только в занавеске. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_NONE` ‎Уведомление с не важно: не показывать в занавеске. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED` Значение, означающее, что пользователь не выразил важность. ‎

---

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager)