# RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-notification, android-gradle

Сейчас для того чтобы опубликовать обновление приложения в PlayМаркет, требуется API не ниже 26. Иначе выдает ошибку:

> Целевой уровень API для вашего приложения – 25. Чтобы обеспечить
>   необходимую производительность и безопасность, целевой уровень API
>   должен быть не ниже 26. Установите для своего приложения целевой
>   уровень API не менее 26.

Если в build.gradle я изменяю `targetSdkVersion` с `25` на `27` то приложение компилируется и заливается в маркет без ошибок, но на устройствах с Android 8.0 получаю краш приложения, связанный с notification, который отображается в шторке андроида (приложение плеер). Какие изменения с этим notification я должен произвести, чтобы всё работало стабильно?

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        //noinspection ExpiringTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    signingConfigs {
    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            //shrinkResources true
            //useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile ('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile ('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    configurations {
        all{
            exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/version.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/http/client/version.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.2.5.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.2.5.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.claucookie.miniequalizer:library:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rm:rmswitch:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.2'
    implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    implementation ('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:2.9.2@aar')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
  //  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.16'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2'
    implementation 'org.ini4j:ini4j:0.5.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    implementation 'org.quuux.feller:feller:0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    //Custom Toasts
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.1.3'

    // ButterKnife (for sample code brevity)
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    // Android architecture components
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'



    // Check for v11.4.2 or higher
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

    // Google Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:11.8.0'

    // Firebase Google
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.wrdlbrnft:sorted-list-adapter:0.2.0.19'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    // android support-v7 27.1.1

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**логи ошибки:**

```
2018-11-14 17:14:55.375 13641-13641/com.test.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.app, PID: 13641
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 category=transport actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2018-11-14 17:14:55.564 13641-13641/com.test.app E/UncaughtException: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x42 color=0x00000000 category=transport actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**PlaybackNotification.java:**

```
public class PlaybackNotification {

    public static Notification getInstance(final Context context, final Bitmap bitmap, final MediaSession mediaSession) {
        final Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        final Streamer stream = Streamer.getInstance();
        final Station station = stream.getStation();
        final StreamMetaData metadata = stream.getLastMetaData();

        String text = metadata!= null ? metadata.getTitle() : null;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text))
            text = station.getNetwork();
        final int playbackIcon = stream.isPlaying() ? R.mipmap.ic_player_pause : R.mipmap.ic_player_play;
        final String playbackText = context.getString(stream.isPlaying() ? R.string.action_pause : R.string.action_play);
        final Intent playbackIntent = new Intent(context, PlaybackService.class);
        playbackIntent.setAction(PlaybackService.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK);

        final Intent stopIntent = new Intent(context, PlaybackService.class);
        stopIntent.setAction(PlaybackService.ACTION_STOP_PLAYBACK);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            final PlaybackState.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder()
                    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1)
                    .setActions((stream.isPlaying() ? PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE : PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY) | PlaybackState.ACTION_STOP);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_ui_radio);
        if (bitmap != null)
            builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
        builder.setContentTitle(station.getName()
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 1. ","")
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 2. ","")
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 3. ","")
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 4. ",""));
        builder.setContentText(text);

            mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build());
            final MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata.Builder()

                    .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_ICON, bitmap)
                    .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ART, bitmap)
                    .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_TITLE, text)
                    .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE, station.getName())
                    .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, text)
                    .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, station.getName())
                    .build();
            mediaSession.setMetadata(mediaMetadata);

            builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            final Notification.Action play = new Notification.Action.Builder(playbackIcon, playbackText, PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, playbackIntent, 0)).build();
            builder.addAction(play);

            final Notification.Action stop = new Notification.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_stop, context.getString(R.string.stop), PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, stopIntent, 0)).build();
            builder.addAction(stop);

            builder.setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1).setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()));

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            builder.addAction(playbackIcon, playbackText, PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, playbackIntent, 0));
            builder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_stop, context.getString(R.string.stop), PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, stopIntent, 0));
        }

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AllStationActivity.class);
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0));

        return builder.getNotification();
    }
}
```

**PlaybackService.java:**

```
public class PlaybackService extends Service implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = Log.buildTag(PlaybackService.class);
    public  static String stopButtonNotification = "";
    public static final String ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK = "com.test.app.actions.TOGGLE_PLAYBACK";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP_PLAYBACK = "com.test.app.actions.STOP_PLAYBACK";
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE_PLAYBACK = "com.test.app.actions.PAUSE_PLAYBACK";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.test.app.actions.STOP";
    public static String focusLoss = "";
    public final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1231231;
    final Streamer streamer = Streamer.getInstance();
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;
    private RemoteControlClient remoteControlClient;
    private ComponentName remoteControlReceiver;
    public static MediaSession mediaSession;

    public static Timer mTimerReconnect;
    public static MyTimerReconnect myTimerReconnect;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        EventBus.getInstance().register(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mediaSession = new MediaSession(this, "com.test.app");
            mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, StationActivity.class);
            mediaSession.setSessionActivity(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0));
        } else {
            remoteControlReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), PlaybackReceiver.class.getName());

            final Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
            mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(remoteControlReceiver);
            final PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);

            remoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
        Streamer.getInstance().destroy();
        ensureUnlocked();
        releaseAudioFocus();
        //off
        unregisterRemote();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mediaSession.release();
        }
        mTimerReconnect.cancel();
        myTimerReconnect.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        final String action = intent != null ? intent.getAction() : null;

        if (ACTION_STOP.equals(action)) {
            updateNotification();
            streamer.stopped();
            stopForeground(true);
        }

        if (ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK.equals(action)) {
            togglePlayback();
        } else if (ACTION_STOP_PLAYBACK.equals(action)) {
            stopButtonNotification = "stop";
            streamer.pause();
            Streamer.getInstance().stopped();
            Streamer.getInstance().isStoppedButton();
            releaseAudioFocus();
        } else if (ACTION_PAUSE_PLAYBACK.equals(action)) {
            setPlaying(false);
        } else {

            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    private boolean requestAudioFocus() {
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
    }

    private boolean releaseAudioFocus() {
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final int result = audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED;
    }

    private void ensureLocked() {
        if (wakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "com.test.app");
            wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        if (wifiLock == null) {
            wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "headspace");
            wifiLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    private void ensureUnlocked() {
        if (wakeLock != null) {
            wakeLock.release();
            wakeLock = null;
        }

        if (wifiLock != null) {
            wifiLock.release();
            wifiLock = null;
        }
    }

    public void buildNotification(final Bitmap bitmap) {
        final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Notification notification = PlaybackNotification.getInstance(this, bitmap, mediaSession);
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }

    private void updateNotification() {
        final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final Streamer streamer = Streamer.getInstance();

        if (streamer.isStopped()) {
            nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
            stopForeground(true);

        } else {

            Picasso.with(this).load(streamer.getStation().getIconUrl()).into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, final com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        buildNotification(bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        buildNotification(null);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                        buildNotification(null);
                    }
            });
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startMediaSession() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            return;

        mediaSession.setActive(true);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void stopMediaSession() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            return;

        mediaSession.setActive(false);
    }

    // FIXME support new api
    private void registerRemote() {
        final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (remoteControlReceiver != null) {
            am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(remoteControlReceiver);
        }
        if (remoteControlClient != null) {
            am.registerRemoteControlClient(remoteControlClient);
        }
    }

    private void unregisterRemote() {
        final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (remoteControlReceiver != null) {
            am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(remoteControlReceiver);
        }

        if (remoteControlClient != null) {
            am.unregisterRemoteControlClient(remoteControlClient);
        }
    }

    private void duck() {
        Streamer.getInstance().setVolume(0.3f);
    }

    private void unduck() {
        Streamer.getInstance().setVolume(1);
    }

    public void loadStation(final Station station) {
        Streamer.getInstance().loadStation(station);
    }

    public void togglePlayback() {
        final Streamer streamer = Streamer.getInstance();
        setPlaying(!streamer.isPlaying());
    }

    public void setPlaying(final boolean state) {
        final Streamer streamer = Streamer.getInstance();

        if (!state) {
            streamer.pause();
        } else {
            if (streamer.isStoppedButton())
                streamer.loadStation(streamer.getStation());

            streamer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopPlayback() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(final int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                unduck();
                Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE:
                unduck();
                Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_EXCLUSIVE");
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
                unduck();
                Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK");
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                setPlaying(false);
                Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
                focusLoss = "loss";
                //Streamer.getInstance().isStoppedButton();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                Streamer.getInstance().setVolume(0.1f);
                setPlaying(false);
                PlayerView.stopbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                PlayerView.playbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                duck();
                Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onMetadataUpdated(final StreamMetaDataUpdate update) {
        updateNotification();
    }





    private static class MyTimerReconnect extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Streamer streamer = Streamer.getInstance();
                    if (Streamer.getInstance().isBuffered()){
                        streamer.loadStation(streamer.getStation());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void onStreamerReconnect() {
        if (myTimerReconnect != null) {
            myTimerReconnect.cancel();
        }
        if(mTimerReconnect != null) {
            mTimerReconnect.cancel();
        }

        mTimerReconnect = new Timer();
        myTimerReconnect = new MyTimerReconnect();
        mTimerReconnect.schedule(myTimerReconnect, 5000, 3000);
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onPlayerStateChanged(final PlayerStateChange update) {

        try {
            updateNotification();
        }catch (Exception i){
            i.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(i);
        }

        try {
            if(Streamer.getInstance().isPlaying()){
                switch (settingsMain.getString(RECONNECT_STATION, "")) {
                    case "1":
                        onStreamerReconnect();
                        break;
                    case "0":
                        //
                        break;
                    default:
                        onStreamerReconnect();
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }

        if (!Streamer.getInstance().isStopped()) {
            ensureLocked();
            requestAudioFocus();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                startMediaSession();
            } else {
                registerRemote();
            }
        } else {
            ensureUnlocked();
            releaseAudioFocus();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                stopMediaSession();
            } else {
                unregisterRemote();
            }
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onError(final PlayerError error) {
        updateNotification();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onStationUpdate(final StationUpdate update) {
        updateNotification();
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public PlaybackService getService() {
            return PlaybackService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте: [[1](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)]

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel("Channel Player", "Player", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
}
```

Сюда:

```
public void buildNotification(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification notification = PlaybackNotification.getInstance(this, bitmap, mediaSession);

    // аля так
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel("Channel Player", "Player", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
    }

    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

А также необходимо добавить:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    builder.setChannelId("Channel Player");
}
```

Сюда:

```
final PlaybackState.Builder stateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder()
                    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 1)
                    .setActions((stream.isPlaying() ? PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE : PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY) | PlaybackState.ACTION_STOP);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_ui_radio);
        if (bitmap != null)
            builder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
        builder.setContentTitle(station.getName()
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 1. ","")
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 2. ","")
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 3. ","")
                .replace(" ᵗᵒᵖ 4. ",""));
        builder.setContentText(text);

        //аля так
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId("Channel Player");
        }
```

---

*По поводу:*

> всегда будет поверх приложения появляться и со звуком уведомления? [[3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893314/android-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/893357#893357)]

Необходимо изменить:

> NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH [[2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager)]

Под свои нужды:

- `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`  По умолчанию значение уведомления: показывает
  везде, шумит, но визуально не вмешиваться. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` ‎Большее значение уведомления: показывает везде, делает шум и заглядывает.
- `IMPORTANCE_LOW` ‎Низкая важность уведомления: показывает везде, но не навязчивым. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_MAX` Неиспользуемые. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_MIN` Значение min уведомления: показывает только в занавеске. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_NONE` ‎Уведомление с не важно: не показывать в занавеске. ‎
- `IMPORTANCE_UNSPECIFIED` Значение, означающее, что пользователь не выразил важность. ‎

---

Источники: [1](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification), [2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893314/android-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/893357#893357)

Comment: ничего не изменилось, всё та же ошибка..

Comment: @Антон а такой пермишн присутствует? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

Comment: @Антон запутался я в вашем коде) надеюсь обновлённый ответ поможет

Comment: да пермишн присутствует.

Comment: А notification который теперь появляется, (слава богу) , всегда будет поверх приложения появляться и со звуком уведомления?

Comment: @Антон обновил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Поставил `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);` надеюсь это правильное решение. Мне нужно чтобы уведомление вообще не мешало и отображалось просто только в шторке и без звуков (не совсем понял, что значит "В тени")

Comment: @Антон 'занавески' скорее всего, ну это машинный перевод просто :D оригинал `Min notification importance: only shows in the shade, below the fold. `, источники я указал навсякие

Comment: )) ок, понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Антон рад был помочь:)